# How to calculate unique elements in collections?

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I have collection like

```
id : 1, url : youtube.com
```

also one url can be many times,

I need get whole collections and count unique elements 
like

```
youtube 10
google   8
lycos    5
```

here is the code

```
  public List<URLEntity> findAll() {
        List<URLEntity> list = new ArrayList<URLEntity>();
        String sort = "searchDate";
        String order = "desc";
        DBObject sortCriteria = new BasicDBObject(sort, "desc".equals(order) ? -1 : 1);

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();           
        DBCursor cursor = mongoCoreService.getDomainCollection().find(query).sort(sortCriteria);
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBObject document = cursor.next();
                URLEntity entity = new URLEntity();
                entity = Converter.toObject(URLEntity.class, document);
                list.add(entity);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Not clear what you want exactly here but you probably want to look into `Set`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I found and test answer in java, here is a code

```
DBCollection mycoll= db.getCollection("domain");

    DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("domain", 1);
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

    // Now the $group operation
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$domain");
    groupFields.put("total", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

    // run aggregation
    AggregationOutput output = mycoll.aggregate(project, group);
    System.out.println(output.getCommand().toString());

    for (DBObject dbObject : output.results()) {
        System.out.println(dbObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using the aggregate framework from MongoDB.

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate({ $group: { _id: '$url', total: {$sum: 1} }})
```

You'll obtain something like this, that you can manipulate in JAVA:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "youtube.com",
        "total" : 10
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "google.com",
        "total" : 8
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "lycos",
        "total" : 5
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```